# Haskell: Lambda function - error - escape their scope

Tags: haskell, lambda

I have the following module defined:

```
module ComplexCompose where

isEven x =
 if x `rem` 2 == 0 then
  (True, "Is Even")
 else
  (False, "Is Odd")


negateIt x = ( not x, "negated")



composer x =
 (c, b ++ ", " ++ d) where (a,b) = isEven x
                           (c,d) = negateIt a
```

The following modification to composer works fine:

```
composerV1 x f g =
 (c, b ++ ", " ++ d) where (a,b) = f x
                           (c,d) = g a
```

I want to make the composer function return a lamda that composes f and g. I tried this:

```
composerV2 f g =
     \x -> (c, b ++ ", " ++ d) where (a,b) = f x
                                     (c,d) = g a
```

It doesn't work. What is the problem with this version?

Compiler output:

```
 • Couldn't match expected type ‘t0 -> (t5, t4)’
                  with actual type ‘t3’
        because type variables ‘t4’, ‘t5’ would escape their scope
      These (rigid, skolem) type variables are bound by
        the inferred type of
        a :: t5
        b :: t4
        at complex-compose.hs:27:34-44
    • In the expression: f x
      In a pattern binding: (a, b) = f x
      In an equation for ‘c4’:
          c4 f g
            = \ x -> (c, b ++ ", " ++ d)
            where
                (a, b) = f x
                (c, d) = g a
    • Relevant bindings include
        a :: t5 (bound at complex-compose.hs:27:35)
        b :: t4 (bound at complex-compose.hs:27:37)
        f :: t3 (bound at complex-compose.hs:26:4)
        c4 :: t3 -> (t2 -> (t1, [Char])) -> t -> (t1, [Char])
          (bound at complex-compose.hs:26:1)
```

Btw, the following simple function works:

fn f g =
     \x = g(f x)

Comment: I would start by adding type signatures to all of your top-level functions. Even if that doesn’t fix the problem, it will almost certainly make your type errors much more comprehensible.

Comment: You might enjoy pondering the following definition: `foo = (\x -> x+v1, \x -> x++v2) where v1 = 3*x; v2 = "hello, " ++ x`. Which `x` (if any) should be in scope in that `where` clause? What type should it have? (For the purposes of this question, the interesting nugget in the question remains even if you reduce the complexity by saying that all numeric literals are `Integer` so we don't have any oddities with Haskell's `Num` hierarchy.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`composerV2` type-checks for me if I don't write the `x` on the left-hand side:

```
composerV2 f g x =
     (c, b ++ ", " ++ d) where (a,b) = f x
                               (c,d) = g a
```

The problem is that in the `where` clause, the identifier `x` wasn't actually in scope. The error message is kind of confusing, but becomes precise if you add a type signature, which is good practice anyway.

Alternatively, you could have used a `let` binding.

Note that `composerV2 f g = let ... in \x -> ...` and `composerV2 f g x = ...` are semantically the same, since you can just partially apply the second version.

Edit: The version using a `let` binding looks like this:

```
composerV2' f g = \x ->
  let (a,b) = f x
      (c,d) = g a
  in (c, b ++ ", " ++ d)
```

Comment: I want composer to return a lambda that composes f and g. That's my intention

Comment: Like I said, this is what this version already does. The function arrow associates to the right, so any function of type `a -> b -> c -> d` can alternatively be read as `a -> (b -> (c -> d))`. So you can get your function like `let myLambda = composeV2 f g`.